# having too many S processess in my server

Tags: linux

my server has too many S state processes and it is increasing anyway.
but the weird thing is every thing is normal in my system.for example cpu utilization or memory usage is normal.
I would appreciate if anyone could help me.
[image]

Comment: I mean, admittedly, 19 zombie processes are quite a few, but then again, you have > 4000 tasks in total, so maybe it's not that bad. Which are these zombie processes? That seems to be very important.

Comment: The server had processes about 400 but one day it started to increasing and i dont know the reason.the about 99 percent of these are in the S state and they dont use any resource.but i want to know how to stop them and also to know if they are going to get us into trouble@MarcusMüller